# PHP обработка POST запроса

Tags: php, веб-сервер

Здраствуйте, пишу приложение которое должно отправить POST запрос на сервер. А сервер в свою очередь должен записать все что было в POST запросе в текстовик. Клиентом будет являться C# программа вот код

```
string text= "TEST POST REQUEST";
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://MY_EXAMPLE_SITE/post");
request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentLength = text.Length;
using (var writer = new StreamWriter(request.GetRequestStream()))
{
    requestWriter.Write(text);
}
```

А сервер должен обработать этот запрос и записать в текстовик всю информацию о запросе, и текст запроса. **Сервер на PHP**. Прошу помочь написать скрипт для обработки POST запроса!

Comment: А в чем собственно проблема ?

Comment: Я так понимаю, что вам нужен скрипт, который будет в `http://MY_EXAMPLE_SITE/post` ? Дополните вопрос.

Comment: `file_put_contents`

Comment: Код записывает в файл содержимое post запроса. Вам нужно вот всего лишь это ? `<?php  $f=fopen("contents_post.txt","w"); 
 fwrite($f,print_r($_POST,true));  fclose($f)  ?>`